# Solving the inequality $\frac{|x + 3| + x}{x + 2} > 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have an inequality which is as follows

> If $x\in \mathbb R$ , solve the following inequality for $x$
>   $$\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}\gt 1$$

I rearranged and got this 
$$|x+3|\gt2$$

solving for it gives me $x\in(-\infty,-5)\cup (-1,\infty)$

But putting $-6$ in original inequality is making the statement false

I told it to my friend and he got $x\in R-[-2,-1]-\{-5\}$

And he is right ,

But I want to know why am I wrong and how to approach the correct answer??

Please help!!

Comment: you can't multiple by a variable term both the sides to solve a inequality. @AtulMishra

Comment: I don't believe it @HarshKumar

Comment: Just read the answer of Jean Marie...

Comment: He said about the negatives your comment is about everything @HarshKumar

Comment: To be more precise, you cannot multiply by an expression whose sign you don't know. (But it would be fine to multiply by $x^2+1$, for example, since it's always $\ge 1$ and hence positive.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You error comes from the fact that, in your "rearranging" process, you have (maybe without noticing it) had to multiply both sides of your inequality by $(x+2)$ but, doing that, you have implicitly assumed that $x+2>0$. If, on the contrary, $x+2<0$, you have to **reverse** the inequality symbol, i.e., your inequality becomes

$$(x+2)\left(\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}\right)\lt (x+2) \ \ \iff \ \ |x+3|+x \lt x+2 \ \ \iff \ \ |x+3| \lt 2$$

Comment: Ahh , I got that....

Answer (score 2):

I like to make it easy to myself by first solving:

$$f(x)=\frac{|x+3|+x}{x+2}-1=0$$

We get:

$$|x+3|+x=x+2$$
$$|x+3|=2$$
$$x=-5 \lor x=-1$$

Furthermore, $x$ cannot be $-2$ else we would divide by $0$. $f(x)$ is a continuous function except at $x=-2$. By simply choosing some values for $x$ we get:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
x & &-5 && -2 && -1 \\
\hline
f(x) & -&0&+ & \text{X}&- & 0&+\\
\end{array}
$$

**Therefore: $x\in(-5,-2)\cup(-1,\infty)$**

Comment: I think it's the best way here. +1

Answer (score 1):

your inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{|x+3|-2}{x+2}>0$$
now we do case work:
1)$$x\geq -3$$ then we get $$\frac{x+1}{x+2}>0$$
a) if $x+2>0$ then we have $x+1>x+2$ which is impossible
b) if $x+2<0$ then $x+1<x+2$ which is true.
and we get
$$-3\le x<-2$$
can you finish?
you can not multiply be $x+2$ because this can be negative

Comment: But what was mistake in my process @Dr.SonnhardGraubner sir?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general method: split the problem into cases to remove the absolute value signs.

Case 1: if $x+3>0$ or $x>-3$，then $|x+3|=x+3$, so the equation can be expressed as:
$$
\frac{x+3+x}{x+2}>1
$$

Solving this inequality, we get:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2x+3}{x+2}-1>0\\
\frac{2x+3-(x+2)}{x+2}>0\\
\frac{x+1}{x+2}>0
\end{align}$$

From the above, either $
\begin{cases}
 x+1>0\\
 x+2>0\\
\end{cases}
$ or
$
\begin{cases}
 x+1<0\\
 x+2<0\\
\end{cases}
$, which implies $x>-1$ or $x<-2$. Also because $x>-3$, obtaining their intersection, we obtain:
$$
x \in (-3,-2) \cup (-1,\infty)
$$

Scenario 2: if $x+3<0$, $x<-3$，or $|x+3|=-(x+3)$. We can write this as:
$$
\frac{-(x+3)+x}{x+2}>1
$$
and solving the inequality:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{-3}{x+2}-1>0\\
\frac{-3-(x+2)}{x+2}>0\\
\frac{-x-5}{x+2}>0\\
\frac{x+5}{x+2}<0
\end{align}$$

The above can be resolved as $
\begin{cases}
 x+5>0\\
 x+2<0\\
\end{cases}
$ or
$
\begin{cases}
 x+5<0\\
 x+2>0\\
\end{cases}
$, hence $x \in (-5,-2)$ or $x \in (- \infty,-5) \cap (-2,\infty)$ (the empty set, so discard it). Also since $x<-3$, obtaining their intersection we have:
$$
x \in (-5,-3)
$$

Finding the intersection of cases $1$ and $2$, the final answer is:
$$
x \in (-5,-2) \cup (-1,\infty)
$$

Comment: 这里最好用英文：虽然没有不允许中文 (看看这里: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/asking-questions-in-a-language-other-than-english?noredirect=1&lq=1), 能中翻英的人不多，与人沟通会有困难。

Answer (score 0):

Shift the given function two units to the right to get:

$$\frac{|x+1| + x-2}{x} > 1 \implies \frac{|x+1| - 2}{x} > 0$$

Now we can separate the problem into cases, which makes the casework a little easier. When $x > 0 $, multiplying by $x$ gives $|x + 1| > 2 \implies$ $ |x - (-1)| > 2 \implies x < -3, 1 < x$, but only $1 < x$ is valid as both inequalities must be satisfied. Similarly, when $x < 0$, $|x + 1| < 2 \implies -3 < x < 1$, however only $-3 < x < 0$ is valid. When $x = 0$, the left-hand side is undefined, so $x \ne 0$.

To recover the original solution of the inequality, move two units back to the left, which means replacing $x$ with $x + 2$.

This results in $\boxed{x \in (-5, -2) \cup (-1, \infty)}$.

Comment: See how the problem is made much easier this way? The inequality sign flips when $x < 0$ and remains the same when $x > 0$, and we can exploit this inequality to use the cases more effectively.